# How to deserilize json in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am getting this response.How to deserilize the JSON?

```
[{
    "NoOfRecord":"2",
    "data":[ 
    {
    "name": "Pinky",
    "Id": "8989898",
    "PhoneNumber": "918934",
    "status": "Success",
    },
    {
    "name": "Kajol",
    "Id": "2345678",
    "PhoneNumber": "915566",
    "status": "Fail",
    }
    ]
}]
```

I tried like this, but getting error.

I have created 2 classes for that.

```
public class JsonResult2
{
    public string NoOfRecord{ get; set; }
    public JsonData Data { get; set; }
}

public class JsonData 
{
   public string name{ get; set; }
   public string Id{ get; set; }
   public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
   public string status{ get; set; }
}
```

When I am writing like this, getting error.

```
 var JsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult2>(ResponseJson);
```

I am using Newtonsoft's library(using Newtonsoft.Json;)

How to access all `name`,`id`,`phonenumber` and `status`.

I am storing obtained response in string called `ResponseJson`.

> Error : Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'JsonResult2'

Comment: Can you please share the what is the error that you're getting??

Comment: Error : Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'JsonResult2'

Comment: Change the property name "Count" of JsonResult2 to "NoOfRecord". Also, after deserialzing you can access properties like - JsonData.JsonData.name, etc.

Comment: Done that still facing a problem

Comment: Just use this page http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your JSON string is invalid. It has two commas as shown below which shouldn't be there:

```
[{
    "NoOfRecord":"2",
    "data":[ 
    {
    "name": "Pinky",
    "Id": "8989898",
    "PhoneNumber": "918934",
    "status": "Success", <-- This comma shouldn't be there
    },
    {
    "name": "Kajol",
    "Id": "2345678",
    "PhoneNumber": "915566",
    "status": "Fail", <-- This comma shouldn't be there
    }
    ]
}]
```

Once those commas are removed, your JSON is valid. Here's how it would look:

```
[{
    "NoOfRecord":"2",
    "data":[ 
    {
    "name": "Pinky",
    "Id": "8989898",
    "PhoneNumber": "918934",
    "status": "Success"
    },
    {
    "name": "Kajol",
    "Id": "2345678",
    "PhoneNumber": "915566",
    "status": "Fail"
    }
    ]
}]
```

Now the outermost brackets `[]` mean that you are receiving an array, not object. So your de-serialization syntax should be:

```
var JsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult2>>(ResponseJson);
```

Then you need to ensure that the properties in the JSON match those of your entities. Also note the two `[]` square brackets against `data` in the JSON. That means you are expecting an array, not object. That means `Data` should be  `List<JsonData>` instead of `JsonData`. So you'd need to update `JsonResult2` as follows:

```
public class JsonResult2
{
    public string NoOfRecord { get; set; }
    public List<JsonData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Also, if you are certain that `NoOfRecord` is a number, you might want to change the type of NoOfRecord within `JsonResult2` to `int`.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: I am not the downvoter. My guess would be because you however have provided the wrong answer. `Data` should be an collection of `JsonData` based on the JSON in the OP ie `public IList<JsonData> data { get; set; }`

Comment: @Nkosi thanks, I had missed that.

Comment: You should also let the OP know that they are deserializing to the wrong type. everything is wrapped in an array so they need to ask for `JsonResult2[]` hence the error message about not being able to deserialize JSON array into type 'JsonResult2'

Comment: @Nkosi It's astonishing how many details I had missed. I hadn't even noticed that their JSON is invalid. There are a bunch of commas `,` before closing brackets `}`. I will update the answer. Thanks a lot!